# Matplotlib toggle artist using blit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to show/hide some elements to a plot scene conditionally based on key pressed. I do not want the entire canvas to be redrawn because of speed. Therefore I would like to use blit techniques. I tried out, but for some reason, my background does not get restored. 
Here is a simple example of what I would like to reach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
class LinePlot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        'connect to all the events we need'
        self.cidpress = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect(
                'key_press_event', self.on_keypress)
        self.line_drawn=False
        self.rectangle_drawn=False
    def plot(self):
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        x=np.random.random(size=1000)
        y=np.random.random(size=1000)
        self.collection=self.ax.scatter(x,y,marker='+',color='red')
        plt.show()
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
    def on_keypress(self,event):
        if event.key=='r':
            if not self.line_drawn:
                self.line=Line2D([0,0.5],[0,1])
                self.ax.add_line(self.line)
                self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
                self.fig.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
                self.line_drawn=True
            else:
                self.line.set_animated(True)
                background=self.fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.line.axes.bbox)
                self.line.set_animated(False)
                self.fig.canvas.restore_region(background)
                self.line_drawn=False                
                self.fig.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
        if event.key=='b':
            if not self.rectangle_drawn:
                self.rect=Rectangle((0.1,0.2),0.2,0.3,facecolor='green')
                self.ax.add_patch(self.rect)
                self.ax.draw_artist(self.rect)
                self.fig.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
                self.rectangle_drawn=True
            else:
                self.rect.set_animated(True)
                background=self.fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.rect.axes.bbox)
                self.rect.set_animated(False)
                self.fig.canvas.restore_region(background)
                self.rectangle_drawn=False                
                self.fig.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)

p=LinePlot()
p.plot()
```

If the 'r' key is pressed, the line should appear/disappear, if the 'b' key gets pressed, the rectangle should appear/disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens with the code? The `blit` stuff is backend-specific, so which backend are you using? (i.e. what does `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; print plt.get_backend()`) report?

Comment: The backend I'm using is QT4Agg.

Comment: The code will show the line or rectangle when the first time the r or b key is pressed, but when the second time, the key is pressed, the line will still be there (background not restored). A third time will draw a second line or rectangle over the previous one. It seems that either the background restoring doesn't work well or that even though the line and/or rectangle is set to animated, they are still in the background.
Is there a way to see what is in fact stored in the background variable?

Comment: Unfortunately my current platform does not allow experimenting (does not support `canvas.copy_from_bbox`), but the method should AFAIK return a pixel buffer, whose format depends on the backend. You would most likely be quite able to decipher its contents by a bit of experimenting.